# deque<bool> iterator compile error

Tags: c++

How to use deque to print its items?

The below code results with a build error:

> fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrCalcPtrs

```
deque<bool> mandy3;
mandy3.push_back(true);
mandy3.push_back(false);
mandy3.push_back(true);

for(deque<bool>::iterator it=mandy3.begin(); it!=mandy3.end(); it++)
    printf("mandy3 : %d" , *it?1:0);
```

Comment: Try to rebuild your whole project.

Comment: VC++2008 does that quite often, re-building it "fixes" the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a compiler error, it's a linker error. It occurs while using the incremental linking feature, so do a clean build (rebuild) to clear out old files.